# Using a ground wire as a thermostat C

Tags: electrical, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

Just theoretically, A C wire is just a return for 24v transformer right? So if you were in a situation where you have access to the slab, or just a standard outlet or switch receptacle could you wire nut a wire from ground to C?

Answer (score 7):

#### No way!

A "return" is not the same thing as a "ground". In certain situations it is, but not here. The C wire (together with "the other half of the circuit") forms a circuit through the **secondary** of the 24V transformer. The primary (at 120V) is a circuit through hot and neutral. While, from a purely theoretical (but not safe!) standpoint, that ground on the primary is "the same as" neutral, and therefore a logical (but not safe!) substitute, that is absolutely **not** the case for the secondary, which is where you find the C wire.

In addition, let's just say hypothetically that things actually worked that way, **which they do NOT**. If they did, then if you ever had a neutral/ground fault, conducting many Amps of current at 120V (not 24V!) through the ground system, some of that would end up not only on your 24V transformer (frying it) but also would leak over to the control circuits of your HVAC system and to your thermostat, which would most assuredly **not be a good thing**.

But the bottom line is that it won't even work at all, because that ground is on the wrong side of your transformer.

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is wrong anyway.   Current wants to return to source, not ground.

Ground is not a current return in any respect.  A lot of people think it is, either because they come out of low voltage electronics where "GND" is used to describe common... or  because they are aware of the equipotential bond between neutral and ground in the main panel.

Also, 24V is an *isolated system* that has no relationship with ground.

Comment: I have always seen the 24V AC isolated, but there was a recent question (2021) where OP showed the furnace's 24V side common bonded to the chassis, by design and as documented in the schematic.   I don't know why the 24V might be better isolated or clamped to ground, but in (rare?) cases like this, it is possible the thermostat could leech the power it needs using the home grounding system as a return path to the 24V transformer C side.  Not recommending it, just saying it's not magic if it works.

Comment: I've seen this before too. What you have to do is connect your c wire to the exact spot the tx common is attacked to ground.That way, the path is completed without going through ground

Comment: Well that's odd, for 5 years I have 20 nest T-stats that were installed to systems with no C wire. The C wire was screwed to metal paneling which was apparently grounded. They are all still working along with the 15 installed since then. The buildings all had sheetmetal on the walls where the nests were installed.

Comment: @Shawn  Old dimmers power themselves by leaking small current through the bulb. Incandescents won't light in that case. (LEDs will). Many Nest models will probe the furnace and A/C actuators to see if the same trick will work. If so, they don't need C.  As for ground, the 24V thermostat system is generally isolated from ground, so ground wouldn't work as a current return for that. Electricity does not care about getting "back to ground".  It wants to get back to *source* i.e. the transformer.  With mains power, we ground the neutral.  With thermostat power, we generally don't ground C.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a HVAC pro. I am a mechanic and a homeowner. In my Goodman furnace, the C wire is connected to the 24v secondary/chassis or frame ground of the unit. It is also common with the 110~120 volt system ground. Wiring to the ground @ any outlet would potentially work, but is not good practice,as many things could go wrong and possibly short or overload the circuits in your furnace controls, not good! Happy trails.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I bought a small transmitter receiver for my old 2 wire system.
Ugly solution to run a wire from nearby outlet ground to C in therostat
and then connect c in heater to metal
side.  primary of transformer would need to float.  not electrician but sounds unsafe.

Answer (score -1):

Let's talk AC power here for a minute. In your 120v AC power system, you've a hot lead and a common lead. If your panel's fed with 240v single phase, you have, in your panel, 2 "legs" of AC, and a common point. For 120vAC, either one of those legs to common has a 120vAC path.

Main panels tend to tie common to ground, so yes... tying to common (the white wire in your electrical cord) or to ground means things are going to the same place. Note that subpanels isolate common and ground.

Some older panels didn't work this way, and some industrial systems don't tie common directly to ground. I worked on a computer power system once with 6v differential between common and ground that had to be better balanced.

Comment: "panels tend to tie common to ground"  This isn't actually true.  Your main panel will have the neutral tied to ground but all sub panels by code should have their neutral and ground isolated.

Comment: Thank you. I misspoke and have corrected my post.